# filtering out other objects - Android Open CV library

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to recognize pedestrian traffic signal.I am converting the image to HSV color space, then applying in-range function to get only green lights.Here is my original image
[image]

This is my code..

```
  public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
switch (status) {
    case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully...................");
            Mat img = null;
            try {
                img = Utils.loadResource(getBaseContext(), R.drawable.glarrygreen, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Mat mHSV = new Mat();
            Mat mRgba2 = new Mat();
            Mat mHSVThreshed = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(img, mHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV, 3);
            //This works for red lights
            Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(0, 64, 200), new Scalar(69, 255, 255), mHSVThreshed);
            //this works for green lights
            Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(85, 64, 200), new Scalar(170, 255, 255),

                mHSVThreshed);
            List < MatOfPoint > contours = new ArrayList < MatOfPoint > ();
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
            Imgproc.findContours(mRgba2, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            double maxArea = -1;
            int maxAreaIdx = -1;
            for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
                Mat contour = contours.get(idx);
                double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
                if (contourarea > maxArea) {

                    maxArea = contourarea;
                    maxAreaIdx = idx;


                }
            }
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mHSVThreshed, img, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR, 0);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(img, mRgba2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA, 0);
            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.cols(), img.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba2, bmp);
        }
}
```

}
This is my output image [image]

Now I need to filter out other green signals in the scene.How do I do this?How do I get the most prominent green signal in the scene.

EDIT 1:
I am trying to use findCountours() method, get list of contours ,iterate through the results and get the largest, then display only the largest contour.How to remove smaller contours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working by using findCountours() and drawContours() methods,

This is how it works,

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mHSVThreshed, mHSVThreshed, new Size(5, 5), 5);
                           Imgproc.findContours(mHSVThreshed, contours,newcont, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
                           double maxArea = -1;
                           int maxAreaIdx = -1;
                           for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
                               Mat contour = contours.get(idx);
                               double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
                               if (contourarea > maxArea) {
                                   maxArea = contourarea;
                                   maxAreaIdx = idx;
                               }
                           }
                          Imgproc.drawContours(img, contours, maxAreaIdx, new Scalar(120, 255, 120), 1);

                        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.cols(), img.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                        Scalar c = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);  
                        Core.putText(img, VAL, new Point(100,100), 3, 1, c, 2); 
                        Imgproc.erode(mHSVThreshed, mHSVThreshed, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(1.5,1.5)));  
                        Utils.matToBitmap(img, bmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to filter your binary image with a non-maxima suppression algorithm.
Here is a [Java Demo of non-max suppression](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/msn/book/new_demo/nonmax/).
Note that NMS algorithm can be coded using morphological function (Erosion and Dilatation).

**EDIT** it seems that opencv already has a NMS function with the following prototype:

```
void nonMaximaSuppression(const Mat& src, const int sz, Mat& dst, const Mat mask)
```

**EDIT2**  From opencv doc: For every possible (sz x sz) region within src, an element is a local maxima of src iff it is strictly greater than all other elements of windows which intersect the given element.

Try with 50x50 patch (sz := 50)

FYI  The method is derived from the following paper: A. Neubeck and L. Van Gool. "Efficient Non-Maximum Suppression," ICPR 2006

Comment: Thank you!! can you please tell what should be passed for sz and mask parameters?